# Add new properties dynamically to a class which belongs to a list of class shown in WPF Datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, class, properties, datagrid

I know there are some questions approaching this but they do not finally get a solution for vb.net and its application to WPF Datagrids.

I am moving a winform application to WPF. My application is mainly based on datagrids, and here comes the problem, because datagrids in wpf are used from a different point of view.

In my old app, I had arrays that were shown in datagrids. As a I moved to WPF I am trying to move them to list of classes for showing them in datagrids.

I need the user to be able to change the number of properties (the number of periods).

How can I accomplish this? I have read that maybe a solution could be to add a dictionary in the class but I don't know how to apply this for creating new properties.

Here is my code:

```
 Public Class Cashflow
    Property Period1 As String
    Property Period2 As String

    Sub New(Period1 As String, Period2 As String)
        Me.Period1 = Period1
        Me.Period2 = Period2
    End Sub

End Class

Public Function GenerateList()
    Dim Cashflows As New List(Of Cashflow)
    Cashflows.Add(New Cashflow("500", "600"))
    Return Cashflows
End Function

Private Sub GenerateListBt_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles GenerateListBt.Click
    'GenerateList()
    Datagrid.ItemsSource = GenerateList()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that we still can use "old" DataGridView's by the use od WindowsFormsHost. It is a WPF control that can be any control you want, but it needs to be configured using XAML code.

So I did not pass my old DataGridViews to WPF Datagrids, I did pass them to WindowsFormsHost's, which I am still configuring. This allows me to re-use the code from the original app.

Although I found this solution, I am still intersted in solving this question using WPF Datagridviews because maybe I will move to this approach in the next future.